# TypeInfo.IsAssignableFrom in Roslyn analyzer

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

In my Roslyn analyzer I get `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypeInfo` of an argument by

```
var argumentTypeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(argumentSyntax.Expression);
```

also I have another instance of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypeInfo` called `targetTypeInfo`. Now I want to know if the type describled by `targetTypeInfo` is assignable from the type describled by `argumentTypeInfo`.

I know `System.Reflection.TypeInfo` has its `IsAssignableFrom` method, which is exactly what I want. But the convertion between the two `TypeInfo`s is a problem. What's the correct way to get type relationships in an analyzer?

Comment: You can check the base classes and implemented interfaces of the `ITypeSymbol` in `TypeInfo` in question. But this might be cumbersome. Another approach which might work is to use the `Compilation.ClassifyConversion` and check the returned `ConversionKind`. A third option is to check how Roslyn binds the `is` operator: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs,507, but I guess it uses the `ClassifyConversion`. Let me know if any of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

What Tamas commented was helpful. It goes in the direction of the solution I found.

Nowadays one can use the `Compilation.HasImplicitConversion(ITypeSymbol? fromType, ITypeSymbol? toType)` method.
This was discussed here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9461 and then added with [PR #26719](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/26719).

This does exactly what I wanted when I found this question.